# Passing variable to wordpress function fails

Tags: php

How is it possible that if I use variable inside this wordpress function it doesn't work?

```
////////
// Creating theme settings
////////
create_theme_setting('theme_social_options');

////////
// function to create theme settings easily
////////
function create_theme_setting($option_name) {

        ////////
        // Theme settings initialize social options
        ////////
        function theme_intialize_options() {
            // If the social options don't exist, create them.
            if (false == get_option($option_name)) {   
                add_option($option_name);
            }

            add_settings_section(
                'social_settings_section',          // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
                'Social Options',                   // Title to be displayed on the administration page
                'social_options_callback',          // Callback used to render the description of the section
                $option_name                        // 
            );

            add_settings_field( 
                'twitter',                      
                'Twitter',                          
                'twitter_callback', 
                $option_name, 
                'social_settings_section'
            );

            register_setting(
                $option_name,
                $option_name,
                'theme_sanitize_options'
            );
        }
        add_action('admin_init', 'theme_intialize_options');
        //
        //
        function social_options_callback() {
            echo '<p>Provide the URL to the social networks you\'d like to display.</p>';
        }
        //
        //
        function twitter_callback() {
            //First, we read the options
            $options = get_option($option_name);
            //Next, we need to make sure the element is defined in the options. If not, we'll set an empty string.
            $url = '';
            if(isset($options['twitter'])) {
                $url = $options['twitter'];
            }
            //Render the output
            echo '<input type="text" id="twitter" name="' . $option_name . '[twitter]" value="' . $options['twitter'] . '" />';
        }
        //
        //
        function theme_sanitize_options($input) {
            $output = array();

            //Loop through each of the options sanitizing the data
            foreach($input as $key => $val) {
                if (isset($input[$key])) {
                    $output[$key] = esc_url_raw(strip_tags(stripslashes($input[$key])));
                }
            }

            //Return the new collection
            return apply_filters('theme_sanitize_options', $output, $input);
        }

} //End create_theme_setting
```

Comment: You sure that you passing the write things to it? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section

Comment: Yes, because if I change $option_name with the actual value 'theme_social_options' it works.

Comment: But it's totally wrong to ask us this way. If there's a function `function myFunc(string $param1, int $param2)` and you are asking us why `myFunc('blabla', $option)` does not work, we can not answer you. Maybe `$option = 'lalala'` but your function expects `int` instead of `string` ? Give us the code where `$option_name` is declared in your case

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui did just now :)

Comment: @RoyalBg I don't know how else to ask :( pasted more code though.

Comment: I still don't see where $option_name is declared

Comment: @RoyalBg first line create_theme_setting('theme_social_options');

Comment: @SandroDzneladze _Note:_ PHP is not javascript. Nesting functions like this does not make any sense, they are still callable from global scope.

Comment: First of all, a called function (`create_theme_setting()`) does not assign a value to a variable. If `create_theme_setting` returns `'theme_social_options` it does not assign its value to the respective variable $option_name. Second, you have a function inside a function, and I'm not sure if the parameter passed to the main function is in scope of inner functions. Separate the functions out the main one, and pass the returned value from the main one

Comment: @RoyalBg: Indeed, I think the OP expects the nested functions to be closures, but AFAIK PHP doesn't work that way (but it's been a while since I used PHP, maybe that has changed?).

Comment: @Leri Yes, I've been writing to much js lately... :) I'm trying to automate setting creation in wp, as it is allot of copy paste to do it manually, hence the nested functions.

Comment: No, it's not, closures are not made this way :) If he needs a closure, then he should use the relevant syntax for that, it ain't work this way :) You are right

Comment: @SandroDzneladze Well, nesting functions like this _does not work_, to make it work you have to use closures, but still it's awful thing to do. For example, `function outer($param) { $inner = function() use($param) { echo $param; }; $inner(); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to create closures here: define the `$option_name` once and use it in the different functions declared inside the function that gets `$option_name` passed as a parameter. However, I think PHP doesn't work that way: the functions just get declared in the global namespace, without variable binding.

To achieve the result you want, you can write the code as a class, with the different functions as methods of that class. Then instantiate objects of that class, with `$object_name` as a property. Now you can access `$this->object_name` from the different methods. Remember to [pass the object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_add_action_with_a_class) to `add_action`, not the class, something like this:

```
// There might be syntax errors here, it's been a while since I wrote PHP code
class SettingTheme {
    public function __construct($option_name)
    {
         $this->option_name = $option_name
         add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'theme_intialize_options'));
    }

    public function theme_intialize_options() {
    {
        if (false == get_option($this->option_name)) {   
            add_option($this->option_name);
        }

        // ...
    }
}

$st = new SettingTheme('theme_social_class');
```